# Amazon SQS better way of handling listeners

Tags: multithreading, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have an SQS Queue which has a lot of messages (typically in thousands). Presently I am having multiple listeners (which are created by threads created from the same source) and each listener listens to the queue and receives messages. As soon as a listener receives a message from the Queue, that listener deletes the message from the Queue. The message will be processed only after deleting the message from the queue. I am having a visibility timeout of 30 seconds.

I am not using any locks or anything to handle duplicates since I am deleting the message from the queue as soon as after receiving. I haven't seen a case of duplicity until now but I am just worried it might.

Now, the question is, which is a better way, having multiple listeners this way or listening to the queue in a single thread, and then spinning up new threads to process each message you receive?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, it is worth understanding the concept of **message invisibility timeout**.

When a message is retrieved from an Amazon SQS queue (eg by your thread), the message is marked as *invisible* in Amazon SQS. Best-practice is for your thread to then process the message and then **delete the message after it has completed processing the message**. This way, if the thread fails, the message will automatically become visible on the queue again and another thread can process it.

With your current application design, if a thread fails then the message is lost and will not be retried. You should **consider changing your code** to delete the message only *after* it has been processed.

Using multiple threads to process messages is recommended, because it will allow **higher message throughput by processing messages in parallel**. It is also a simpler design, and simple is always best. Your alternate idea of having one process retrieve messages and then firing off threads to process the message is more complex and does not provide any benefits.

Amazon SQS queues **can occasionally return the same message more than once**. It is rare, but can happen. The multiple-thread design will probably result in it happening more than the single-thread design because multiple threads might simultaneously retrieve the same message. However, there **it could still happen in the single-thread model**, too.

If processing the same message twice is a concern, then consider using a [FIFO queue](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/FIFO-queues.html) (not currently available in every AWS Region). This will guarantee that every message is received only once. Alternatively, your code would need to check whether a particular message has already been processed (eg by checking in a database).

The multiple-thread design will also allow you to **horizontally scale** by having multiple system (even across multiple Availability Zones) process messages, whereas your single-thread design has a single point of failure and is less scalable.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your ideas! I will change my code to process the message and then delete it. Also, is there any chance of a race condition between the listeners while picking a message from the queue? As this might create some problems like a listener to stop?

Comment: See: [At Least Once Delivery](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/standard-queues.html#standard-queues-at-least-once-delivery). This would not cause a problem with listeners.

Comment: Thank you! I will explore more on this.